# How to deal with empty RichTextBox selection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, selection, richtextbox

I'm posting here my first message because i had a problem since a few days with my RichTextBox. I'm actually creating a little text editor. The user can change the font, the size and the color of his text. It works great when there is a selection. But when there is not, the highlighting isn't applied. Here is an example :

[Here i put the cursor with no selection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMqZv.png)

I change the font size property in my toolbar to 30.

[I enter a letter, the font size is expected to be 30, but it's still 16.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUIVI.png)

I looked for a solution, but i found nothing. Here is the code that treat the TextChanged event of the FontSize TextBox (I use a modified TextBox that returns directly the text as an integer):

```
    private void ibFontSize_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int val = ibFontSize.Value;
        if (val >= FontSizeMinValue && val <= FontSizeMaxValue)
            rtbTextArea.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(FontSizeProperty, (double)val);
    }
```

So, what's the solution ? Thank you for reading, i wish you a good day. :)

*Nota : The question was marked as a duplicate post. I've seen the mentioned post, i've tried the solution but it doesn't solve all the problem. It works if i enter content directly after changing the font, but if i change the font and click to the RichTextBox, the selection changes so the previous style takes the place of the new. That an awkward situation because the user can choose a new style and click in the RichTextBox, so the new style isn't applied to what he writes.*

Comment: In WinForms you would use `RichTextBox.SelectionFont` - "If no text is currently selected, the font specified in this property is applied to the current insertion point and to all text that is typed into the control after the insertion point."

Comment: Thanks for replying. There's no equivalent in WPF ? If no i wonder why there is a lot of features that doesn't exist by default in WPF.